# Modal Form not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My modal is working ( means when i click button it appears) but the form is not appearing, i have this modal in the index action so i have added `<% @entries.each do |entry| %>` and without it i am h`aving undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class, any suggestions ?

```
<%= link_to "Assign", "#saturday-one", :class => "btn btn-primary", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="saturday-one">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Time Table</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
    <%= simple_form_for(entry) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :subject, as: :select, label: 'Select Subject' %>
    <%= f.association :employee, as: :select, label: 'Assign Employee' %>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

time_table_entries_controller.rb

```
class TimeTableEntriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @entries = TimeTableEntry.all
    end

    def show
        @entry = TimeTableEntry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @entry = TimeTableEntry.new
    end

    def create
        @entry = TimeTableEntry.new(params[:time_table])
        if @entry.save
            redirect_to time_table_entries_url , notice: 'Time table Entries saved'
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @entry = TimeTableEntry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @entry = TimeTableEntry.find(params[:id])
        if @entry.update_attributes(params[:time_table])
            redirect_to time_table_entries_url, notice: 'TimeTableEntry Updated.'
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: At least one element in `@entries` is `nil`. How are you generating this array?

Comment: i got the @entries line from a question here , do you have a better way ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what it is. Can you post the controller action that renders this form?